# Smooth scrolling, scrollspy and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, smooth-scrolling, scrollspy

I'm having an issue when I'm using smooth scrolling and scrollspy on my website. When I click on my nav menu link I'm directed to the appropriate section. In this section I have tabs. When I click on one of the tabs the scrollbar moves up and down.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcn119w7/9/)

Not sure why my JS isn't firing.  Can someone assist?

Sample scrollspy code:

```
var $body = $(document.body); var navHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true) + 80;
$body.scrollspy({
    target: '#leftCol',
    offset: navHeight
});
```

Sample scrolling code:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - 120
            }, 1000);
            return false;
         }
     }
});
```